# parsing bytes (C Windows)

Tags: c, windows, parsing, byte

I have a DWORD value that in Hex might look like:

```
DWORD Val = 0xFF01091A
```

How can I read each byte? What I mean is, how can I read FF, 01, 09 and 1A?

Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with this sort of thing, make sure you understand where the bytes are coming from and if there's the potential that the code might move to non-windows platforms where byte ordering can be different (moving from a big to little endian processor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DWORD x1 = (0xFF01091A & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
DWORD x2 = (0xFF01091A & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
DWORD x3 = (0xFF01091A & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
DWORD x4 = (0xFF01091A & 0x000000FF) >> 0;
```

Comment: That wouldn't give the right result, though; it'd return 0xFF000000, 0x00FF0000, 0x0000FF00, and 0x000000FF. You need to bit-shift the values as well, so x1 >>= 24, x2 >>= 16, and x3 >>= 8.

Comment: You should L-Shift by 24, 16, 8, and 0 bits.

Answer (score 8):

Not really its more like:

```
uint8_t Byte1 = (Val>> 0) & 0xFF;
uint8_t Byte2 = (Val>> 8) & 0xFF;
uint8_t Byte3 = (Val>>16) & 0xFF;
uint8_t Byte4 = (Val>>24) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: your way is actually cleaner :)

Comment: The "& 0xFF" are not required if you are assigning to a uint8_t, but I think they make it clearer what you are doing and there shouldn't be a performance hit as the compiler should be clever enough to figure out that they are superfluous and not generate the extra assembler instructions.

Answer (score 5):

```
DWORD value;
// casts to `char *` are always ok:
unsigned char * bytes = (unsigned char *)&value;
unsigned char third_byte = bytes[2];
```

Keep in mind that this will get the bytes as they are placed in memory: On little-endian machines `bytes[0]` will hold the least significant byte, on big-endian machines it'll hold the most significant one.

If you want to get the bytes by significance, use shifting as suggested in [Efraim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179869/parsing-bytes-c-windows/1179926#1179926).

Comment: Nice and simple, but has different behavior on little endian and big endian systems. I don't think that was the intention.

Comment: @Thorarin: added comment about endianness

Answer (score 2):

Use a union:

```
union Bytes {
    char c[4];
    unsigned int n;
};

int main() {
    Bytes b;
    b.n = 0xFF01091A;
    char c = b.c[2];
}
```

**Edit:** Sorry, this is C++ code. I'm too tired to convert it to C and test it, but you get the idea?

Comment: not much conversion to be done: there's a `union` missing before `Bytes b;` and you should declare `main` as `int main(void)`

Answer (score 1):

AraK's way works. An other way you can do it is:

```
char x1 = *(((char*)&Val) + 0);
char x2 = *(((char*)&Val) + 1);
char x3 = *(((char*)&Val) + 2);
char x4 = *(((char*)&Val) + 3);
```

Watch out though, this way will be sensitive to the endian-ness of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Mask and shift (as suggested in a previous answer) works; a somewhat trickier alternative is "pointer type punning", i.e.

```
xlowbyte = (unsigned char*)(&Val) [0]; /* LSB, 0x1A */
xmidlowb = (unsigned char*)(&Val) [1]; /* 2nd-LSB, 0x09 */
```

etc -- assuming you're on a little-endian machine (which is likely if you use Windows).